# Debugging topshelf as a service

Tags: topshelf

I am having problems running TopShelf as a service and I am not getting much info to help troubleshoot.  I am using dotNet core 2.2.

I get this error when I start it:

> Error: 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion.

Event logs show:

> 1. A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the Test service to connect.
> 2. The Test service failed to start due to the following error:  The service did not respond to the start or control request in
>      a timely fashion.

It message shows a 30 second timeout in the error popup happens in about 1 second.  I don't think its a time out.

I my **current** setup I am using an IHostedService, but I have tried it without this.  Here is the current setup.

```
    var hostBuilder = SetupHost();
    var rc = HostFactory.Run(x =>
                {
                    x.Service<IHost>(s =>
                    {
                        s.ConstructUsing(name => hostBuilder.Build());
                        s.WhenStarted(tc =>
                        {
                            _logger = tc.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Kickoff>>();
                            tc.StartAsync();
                        });
                        s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.StopAsync());
                    });
                    x.RunAsLocalService();
                    x.SetDescription("Test");
                    x.SetDisplayName("Test");
                    x.SetServiceName("Test");

                    x.EnableShutdown();
                    x.OnException(p => ExceptionOccured(p));
                });
```

If you see something glaring people let me know.

My main goal is to find a technique to troubleshoot this.  I've tried logging to a file with system.io but it does not produce results.  I don't know how to debug it or get meaning information.

Comment: What is `_MonolithEventQueueProcessor18 `? Are you trying to do some sort of initialization of it on startup?

Comment: That is the actual service name, I just changed it to test in the post and forgot to update that.  I updated it.

Comment: That 30 second timeout....is that coming from your code? Is there a stack trace available?

Comment: I am not setting the timeout but I notice it's 120 second on the server.    On exception has a log line but nothing is written.  Not sure if it get fired.  I can't tell what is happening.

Comment: @DonChambers I'm encountering the same issue - did you find a resolution / any tips on debugging?